# Discrete Fourier transform, sine function as spectrum

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-processing, fast-fourier-transform

Consider the following (real part) of some signal $x$:

[image]

Can we say $x$ represents the frequency spectrum of an oscillation with a frequency?

I know that the signal represents a sine wave, but can sin be a spectrum? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The Fourier transform is bijective, which means that for any possible spectrum, there is one and only one signal with that spectrum. The converse is also true that for any possible signal, there is one and only one spectrum. This essentially means that anything can be a sepctrum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is evidently "yes", using the inverse Fourier Transform.

Here is the result for the function at hand that I have assumed to be a cosine function over one period : it is clearly a double dirac, as one could await.

[image]

with the following Matlab script :

> ```
> a=40;ic=ifft(cos((-a:a)*pi/a));
> plot(abs(fftshift(ic)));
> ```

Comment: Do we consider the two "jumps" two different frequencies?

Comment: No, in fact, they are symmetrical with respect to the $y$ axis, with resp. abscissas $a$ and $-a$ (one peak only is informative, the other is its mirror image).

Comment: Thank you for your help.